# How to disable DropDownList in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using following markup on my view and Want to disable DropDownList

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("EquipID", "Select Equipment")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquipID)
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList("EquipID", null, "Select Equipment", new { disabled = "disabled"})
```

Your list of equipments comes from `ViewBag.EquipID`.

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Calibration_dbo.Equipment_EquipID". The conflict occurred in database "Calibration", table "dbo.Equipment", column 'EquipID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @jawadhasan Your question specifically asked how to disable a dropdown list, which this and pretty much all answers describe; you never mentioned anything about SQL constraints. Rather than copying and pasting an error message, update your question accordingly to include further details/context.

Comment: @jawadhasan If you don't want users changing the Equipment, you should **always performs those kind of checks server-side**. When you disable a dropdown like that (`disabled="disabled"`), all you're really doing is disabling it on the **client side.** It's [incredibly easy](https://getfirebug.com/) to re-enable it and have your users doing things you don't want them to. To fix your error, just assign whatever EquipID you want to make the default in your action, right before you save it to the DB. That way, no matter what comes from your form, users should always get a proper EquipID.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EquipID",null, "Select Equipment", new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Regards

Comment: This is giving me error, however if I used    @Html.DropDownList("EquipID", null,"Select Equipment", new { disabled = "disabled"})   then the associated EquipID is NULL in Create ActionMethod

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownList("EquipID", "Select Equipment", new { @disabled = "disabled" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquipID)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly check the intelisence of the method you will get the attributes parameter which accept dictionary type. here you can pass one or more html attributes to customize your display according to your requirement.

for your solution you can add following

```
@Html.DropDownList("EquipID", null, "Select Equipment", new { disabled = "disabled"})
```

however if there are more attributes you need to customize/overwrite then you can easily do following

```
@Html.DropDownList("EquipID", null, "Select Equipment", new { disabled = "disabled", color="#ffffff", name="name"})
```

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Calibration_dbo.Equipment_EquipID". The conflict occurred in database "Calibration", table "dbo.Equipment", column 'EquipID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the html attributes as arguments where we set any defined html attributes.

```
@Html.DropDownList("EquipID", "Select Equipment", new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Regards